# How to use strstr on vector string items?

Tags: c++, stdvector

```
vector<string> filtered_items; filtered_items.push_back("test");

for (auto index_name : filtered_items) 
    strstr(index_name, "te");
```

This throws the error -no matching function for call to 'strstr(std::basic_string&, char*)' because of the way index_name is used in strstr. How can I fix this?

Comment: `strstr` is a C function. It doesnt know anything about `std::string`. `std::string` on the other hand has a `find` method

Comment: You don't. `strstr` is for C code and C-style strings, not for C++'s `std::string`s. Where did you read about `strstr`?

Comment: ney: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr yay: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Comment: Bad idea. `strstr` is nasty, even for C-style strings; it should not be part of anyone's toolkit.

Comment: @PeteBecker Even for C-style strings?

Comment: @PaulSanders There's `string_view::find` for C-style strings.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep but what's the gain? If Pete said, "don't use C-style strings, we now have ```string_view```," that would have made sense. But I don't see a functional difference between ```string_view(haystack).find(needle)``` and plain ```strstr```. From looking at the source it might even be slower because ```strstr``` avoids scanning the entire haystack for the terminator in case the needs is found early.

Answer (score 1):

`strstr` is a C function and does not know about `std::string`. Use [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
std::vector<std::string> filtered_items{ "test" };

for (const auto& index_name : filtered_items) {
    auto i = index_name.find("te");
    if ( i != std::string::npos) {
       std::cout << "found";
    }
}
```